# iOS : Resubmit the rejected app after fixing issue

Tags: iphone, app-store, application-loader

My App was rejected by Apple, Now I have fixed the issues and want to upload the updated bundle file, but when I try opening the compressed bundle file using Application loader, I am getting an error "No eligible applications were found" for Applicaton loader. Please suggest solution. Do I need to change anything in the iTunesConnect?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to login in to iTunes connects and need to do again "Ready to submit binary". Right now your app status should be "Rejected". So you must do that first before uploading through Application loader.

http://itunesconnect.apple.com/

Let me know.

Comment: Now i am not able to see "Ready to submit binary" button..Can you help me ?

Comment: For anyone else who is having a hard time finding it, you need to go view your existing version (that was rejected) and it's in the top right corner of that.

Comment: Still a little more information. If the binary was not yet rejected by Apple you can do it yourself. By clicking on -Binary Details- in de -Links- pane on the app version page. And then clicking -Reject this binary-. After doing this the -Ready to submit binary- button should appear on the app version page.

Comment: Hell sir one question in project me try to upload apps in iTunes but reject 2 time so how many time re upload iTunes without my account delete or remove

Answer (score 26):

1. In itunesconnect "App Store" tab and "iOS APP" heading, select
   the rejected version.
2. In the right pane where the description and
   screenshots appear, scroll down to "Build".
3. Click the red minus sign beside the rejected build to remove it.
4. Resubmit the new uploaded version.

Comment: This works. But don't forget to change your build number in your app

Comment: wow, I did not notice that obscure little red minus sign button

Comment: Specifically, it's a hover button, which makes it even more obscure. Bad UX.

Answer (score 8):

You need to click on the "Ready to Submit Binary" button in iTunes Connect first before doing this.

Click on your app - you'll find the button on the top right.

Answer (score 2):

try it in Safari. I was struggling with this in Chrome.