# Build options for uploading new version of app to AppStore?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I had submitted my app and Apple responded to it and rejected it by identifying an issue of auto layout. Now I have done auto layout in my app and built a new archive with a new version and uploaded the archive to the AppStore successfully.

But I don't know what to do next to in the iTunes Build options. Can anyone help me with what to do next? This is first time I'm updating the app.

Comment: Look at these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519188/ios-resubmit-the-rejected-app-after-fixing-issue  

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your build is rejected, not version. So you just have to update your current **Build 
Version,** but application version must be same. And then upload new version on AppStore and you will see new version in **Activity** Tab.

After adding version, click on **App Store** tab, go to your current version, and new build from **Build** section. Now, you can click on **Submit for Review**.

You can also checkout [AppleDoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html) for more information.

Here is the pictorial description to update version from xCode.[image]

Comment: so i don't have to change version in info of my project? @Nirmalsinh

Comment: I updated by answer to update build version from xCode.

Comment: than archive and upload it? @Nirmalsinh

Comment: im getting error while uploading an archive. @Nirmalsinh

Comment: This action could not be completed. Try Again (-22421) . This is error. @Nirmalsinh

Comment: This is not your issue. It may happen many times when Apple server is not responsding. This happen with me as well. Do one things, upload your application from Application Loader.

Comment: upload the archive now what to do next? @Nirmalsinh

Comment: You can check Activity tab in iTune. You can see your version at there.

Comment: its showing me previous rejected version only there. @Nirmalsinh

Comment: possible to share me your credential in a mail for some time. So I can take a look.

Comment: i can share screnshot on skype, if u r there give me ur id. @Nirmalsinh