# My App got rejected .. How can I upload a new binary (IOS)

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

My app got rejected and they want that I upload a new binary.I tried to change the version number and to upload It again but nothing happened.

Comment: I don't know much about the Apple review process, but didn't you get a *reason* for the rejection? Have you tried to fix the underlying problem instead of just changing the version number?

Comment: lol.. i fixed the problems. And I uploaded it again but I need to upload a new binary.

Comment: @OzanGümüstas sometime iTunesConnect shows nothing if you miss asking any permission from user (for eg, asking microphone access, camera, photo library, etc) once you added that one, iTunesConnect turns to Processing. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Go to ItunesConnect > navigate to submit binary Again, and it should work but keep in mind it should stay in "rejected" status until revising it again.

Comment: hmm must I create a new app over iTunes connect ? There is nothing to submit binary again. I can only remove the old build and take a new build

Comment: Please revise this : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519188/ios-resubmit-the-rejected-app-after-fixing-issue